# Seeking for excel shortcut keys formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to select the empty cells in excel parallel to filled cell by shortcut key.

Example:

Suppose Column `A1 - A10` is filled which can be selected by shortcut using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>.

But I like to select empty column cell `B1 - B10` parallel to filled column cell `A1 - A10` by shortcut, hence please help.

Answer (score 1):

You will need at least two more movements:

After the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> shortcut,

1. Release the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.
2. Press <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>.

Comment: Good answer. It might be worth emphasising that you release the Ctrl key but **not** the Shift key.

Comment: This is not useful, My question was to select the the column cell only as parallel to filled column cell without opting filled column cell.

Answer (score 1):

If cells A1:A10 are filled and you would like to select cells B1:B10 using the keyboard, follow the following procedure:

1. Starting at cell A1, press
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> to select A1:A10
2. While continuing to hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd>, press <kbd>Right</kbd> to select A1:B10.
3. While continuing to hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd>, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to change the active cell in the selection to B10
4. While continuing to hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd>, press <kbd>Right</kbd> to select column B1:B10